# How to configure ehcache.xml to use JMS + ActiveMQ + Tomcat and enable tomcat to start even if the JMS server is down?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, ehcache, spring-jms

I a using ehcache with JMS replication and ActiveMQ as a JMS server.
It is currently used to cache database results with Hibernate 3.6.7

My cacheManager is configured as above:

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory" properties="initialContextFactoryName=br.com.sonner.iss.jms.ExampleActiveMQInitialContextFactory,
      providerURL=failover:tcp://localhost:6969,userName=XXX,password=YYYY,
      replicationTopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=topicConnectionFactory,
      replicationTopicBindingName=ehcache,
      getQueueConnectionFactoryBindingName=queueConnectionFactory,
      getQueueBindingName=ehcacheGetQueue"
  propertySeparator=","
   />
```

The replication and failover is working as it should. If the JMS goes down (the replication stops) and the starts over again when the JMS server starts again.

The only problem that I am facing is that if the JMS server is down at the moment of the startup of my app. The app does not start.

Probably because when Spring goes up it reads the hibernate configurations and when hibernate is loading the app just freezes waiting for the broker.

Does anyone has a work-arround this issue?

I am thinking if there is a way to use the spring jmsTemplate configuration to configure ehcache.xml jndi entries.

Comment: You could try to "lazy-load" some beans. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init